# Rails style URL mapping in PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-mapping

Is there any standard library to do Rails style URL mapping in PHP?  I am not using any framework, all the code is hand-written.  Basically, I am looking for a library that does this

example.com/user/1/active

this should map to a user, with id = 1 and status = 2 (those being the parameters).  I should be able to define the map.

Comment: have you looked into htaccess and mod_rewrite?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @martswite - please link to a more recent version of the apache manual

Comment: @AJ my bad just got the first google result :P

Comment: yes, I've looked at mod rewrite, but is there any pure PHP solution?

Comment: Because rewriting URLs is something handled by the web server, not PHP, mod_rewrite is pretty much the only option you have unless you want the PHP file in the path.

Answer (score 2):

There are roughly ten thousand ways to do this in PHP.

I've recently become a fan of [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php), a lightweight bit of router code with some handy convenience methods.  It's not a framework, and doesn't get in the way of you using one if you wanted to.

It's basically little more than "here's a URL pattern, and here's the function to run when the pattern matches."

Comment: klein.php requires 5.3, I'm on 5.2 :(

Comment: I suggest you (or your host) fix that -- 5.2 is no longer being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are really built to handle that automatically, but short of using a framework, you would be best off writing your own .htaccess rules (if you are using linux or os x), or try checking out how say, CakePHP handles url rewriting and base off of that.
Example:

```
http://example.com/name/corey
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1.php?name=$2 [NC,L]
```

That would rewrite the above url to /name.php?name=corey

Answer (score 0):

PHP's purpose is not to handle differently formatted URLs. There should be some custom application logic taking care of this.

You've mentioned that you are not using any framework at this moment, so I would like to propose you to include [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), it's a micro framework based on the components of Symfony 2.

Here's the 'Hello World' example:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
  return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
});

$app->run();
```

You've mentioned that you are currently using PHP 5.2. Silex uses namespaces, which are available from PHP 5.3 and so on, so you will have to upgrade your PHP to take this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Go with Symfony framework. 
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-1-2-toward-a-restful-architecture-part-1

Look at this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services

Comment: Symfony components are decoupled. This means that you can define your routes and use only the Router component.